# Speedup webpage

Tags: html, css, web-development-server

I test speed of my site loading and the result give me the answer for my site's low speed loading is .......

> Resources with a "?" in the URL are not cached by some proxy caching servers. Remove the query string and encode the parameters into the URL for the following resources:

http://mydomain1.com/css/layout.css?v2.2

here how can i Remove the "?"  from the above link and encode the parameter into the url.??

Comment: Put the cursor at the end of the URL and press the delete key a few times.

Comment: It means you should use static file names such as `layout-v2.2.css` and avoid using `?v2.2`

Comment: but next time the layout-v2.2.css edited the browser only shows the cached css.the edited css will not work at the user side..

Comment: What size (in kb) is your css file? If it's not really that big then I wouldn't worry about having the "?v2.2" query string on there. Otherwise maybe look at implementing the solution suggested below by w4rumy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message means you should do it like:

`http://mydomain1.com/css/layout.css/v2.2`

Using a `/` instead of a `?`. How you achieve to parse this on server side depends on the technology you are using.